# Non-standard naturals and goodstein sequences

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic, goodstein-sequences

By the Kirby–Paris theorem, Goodstein's theorem is independent of Peano arithmetic (PA). Therefore there are non-standard models in which every Goodstein sequence terminates. However, Tennenbaum's theorem states that there is no countable recursive non-standard model of PA. So in what sense do Goodstein sequences in non-standard models terminate? Do they terminate after a non-standard number of steps?

Comment: Since Goodstein's theorem is true in the standard model, all Goodstein sequences terminate in the standard model. The independence result provides nonstandard models in which there are Goodstein sequences that *don't* terminate. (But meanwhile, there are also nonstandard models of true arithmetic, so it is also true that there are nonstandard models where all Goodstein sequences terminate.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been essentially answered in a comment, and is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4):

"In what sense do Goodstein sequences in non-standard models terminate?" In the sense that the sentence, in the language of PA, expressing "All Goodstein sequences terminate" is true in some non-standard models of PA. (Of course, it's false in some other non-standard models of PA, because it's not provable in PA.)  If a Goodstein sequence starts with  non-standard number, termination will take a non-standard number of steps.

(I don't see the relevance of Tennenbaum's theorem to any of this.)